# Reference comparison using == operator

Tags: java, scjp

```
public class AutoBoxingAndUnBoxing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Integer x = 127;
        Integer y = 127;
        System.out.println(x == y);//true

        Integer a = 128;
        Integer b = 128;
        System.out.println(a == b);//false
        System.out.println(a); // prints 128
    }
}
```

How come `x==y` is true and `a==b` is false? If it is based on the value(`Integer -128 To 127`) then `'a'` should print `-128` right?

Comment: The range of `Integer` is -2^31 to 2^31 - 1. It's not -128 to 127; that's the range of a `byte`.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing `Integer` objects, the `==` operator might work only for numbers between [-128,127]. Look at the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Since that values you're comparing are not in the mentioned range, the result will be evaluated to `false` unless you use [`Integer#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: ok but what will be the value after 127 if then range is -128 to 127?

Comment: @kittu what do you mean "the value"? These values are cached due to performance issues, values that are out of that range should be compared using `equals`.

Comment: I mean how `a==b` is false in my case? What is happening internally to make it false? :/

Comment: @kittu Because `a` and `b` are not primitives, they're *objects*. Comparing objects should be done using `equals`, it works for 127 because the value is cached, and `==` can (not always) handle it.